# R construct summary of values from columns

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I would like to make an array that summarises the rows of a data frame with the unique values contained within said rows.

with sample the following example code:

```
ref <- c(1:8)

data1 <- c("A","","C","","","","A","")
data2 <- c("A","","","A","C","","","")
data3 <- c("","B","","","","","","B")
data4 <- c("A","B","","","","D","A","")

initial.data <- data.frame(ref, data1, data2, data3, data4)
```

I can obtain what I want with:

```
summary.data <- paste(initial.data[,2], initial.data[,3], 
                  initial.data[,4], initial.data[,5], sep='') 

desired.data <- substring(summary.data,1,1)
```

However, I would like a more parsimonious way of coding this and one that does not assume that each row  may only take one value.

Comment: Try `v1 <- sort(unique(c(initial.data[,-1])));v1[v1!='']`

Comment: @akrun Thanks again, That gave me the unique values in the rows but on my more complex data lost the summary correlation with rows. I have edited the sample code to give a better example.

Comment: In the case of the example data each row may hold one unique value. The columns associated with that row may either have this value or not. I am attempting to retrieve an array of these unique values for all rows which include many empty cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
 apply(initial.data[-1],1, function(x) unique(x[x!='']))
 #[1] "A" "B" "C" "A" "C" "D" "A" "B"
```

Or

```
 substr(do.call(paste0, initial.data[-1]),1,1)
 #[1] "A" "B" "C" "A" "C" "D" "A" "B"
```

Or use `max.col`

```
 initial.data[cbind(1:nrow(initial.data),max.col(initial.data[-1]!='')+1)]
 #[1] "A" "B" "C" "A" "C" "D" "A" "B"
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry my explanation wasn’t clear enough at the beginning.

Comment: @mattbawn No problem.  Glad to know that it worked.  In the beginning, it was the example that created the confusion.